# Parse SQL results by month using timestamp MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, timestamp

I have a small problem with SQL. I need to select ID of rows and group them into arrays (or something) BY MONTH? I have a timestamp column there.
So if there are rows like this:

```
ID Timestamp
1  blalba(1.10.2017)
2  blabla(2.10.2017)
3  blabla(1.5.1996)
```

The output would be like

```
array(
  [5.1996] => array([3]),
  [10.2017] => array([1,2]);
)
```

(Or something like this).
Is this possible in PHP using some PHP libraries? Or Do I have to implement my own class doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for **[`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)**

```
select group_concat(id separator ', ') as myList,
DATE_FORMAT(Timestamp, '%Y-%m') from <YOUR_TABLE>
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(Timestamp, '%Y-%m');
```

Comment: But what about the same month occurring in two different years?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Just realized. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Well you might be handle this on the MySQL side by ordering by month/year:

```
SELECT
    ID, Timestamp
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    DATE_FORMAT(Timestamp, '%Y-%m');
```

This query would return a result set to PHP which would be ordered such that all records in the same month and year would be clustered together.  You could then just iterate this result set and process the records as you want.

Comment: Well. How to manage SQL when the table is named order, 'id' is column I need to store and date_created is column with timestamp? When Im trying to run this SQL output is this error Syntax error near 'order GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(Timestamp, '%Y-%m')' at line 2

Comment: @Johnczek Where does `GROUP BY` appear anywhere in my query?  What I am proposing is that you just do a regular PHP MySQL query, and then order the results such that you can process one month at a time.

Comment: Oh sorry, bad error. This is the right one  Syntax error near 'order ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(Timestamp, '%Y-%m')' at line 3

Comment: Perhaps you have a problem with your PHP code.  The above query should run on MySQL.

Comment: Its error from Adminer tool (something like PHPMyadmin). I didnt tried it in my application yet.